# Set contentDescription for ActionBar's up button

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, accessibility

I'm trying to customize the "Navigate up" default `contentDescription` that is associated with the up button of the `ActionBar` (I'm using ActionBarSherlock).

From `ActionBarView`'s source:

```
public void setHomeButtonEnabled(boolean enable) {
    mHomeLayout.setEnabled(enable);
    mHomeLayout.setFocusable(enable);
    // Make sure the home button has an accurate content description for accessibility.
    if (!enable) {
        mHomeLayout.setContentDescription(null);
    } else if ((mDisplayOptions & ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP) != 0) {
        mHomeLayout.setContentDescription(mContext.getResources().getText(
                R.string.abs__action_bar_up_description));
    } else {
        mHomeLayout.setContentDescription(mContext.getResources().getText(
                R.string.abs__action_bar_home_description));
    }
}
```

so the key would be how to get a reference to `mHomeLayout`. `getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.home)` is not working, as it's returning an ImageView.

How could I do?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 17):

**layout**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**code**

```
public Toolbar toolbar;
...
setContentView(layout);
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle(layoutTitle);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
...
getSupportActionBar().setHomeActionContentDescription("Go Back To XYZ Screen");
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the description with a style?

Comment: getSupportActionBar().setHomeActionContentDescription("Go Back To XYZ Screen"); this saved me. thank you!!

Answer (score 12):

In xml, use "navigationContentDescription"

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    app:navigationContentDescription="@string/back"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here how I can do what you need in a previous project :

```
((View) getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.home).getParent().getParent()).setContentDescription("blablabla");
```

Using viewHierarchy plugin helps me to understand how ActionBar layout is build.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone needs to set the ActionBar's home-button's content-description for [UIAutomator](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html), use

```
((View) getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.home).getParent()).setContentDescription("MANUALLYSET-home-up");
```

and access the view in your [UIAutomatorTestCase](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/UiAutomatorTestCase.html) using

```
new UiObject(new UiSelector().description("MANUALLYSET-home-up").className("android.widget.FrameLayout"));
```

For some reason the additional *.getParent() did not work, instead Android uses some auto-generated content-description value for that parent which may differ in some Android versions (e.g. "app_name, Close navigation drawer" on KITKAT and "app_name, Navigate up" on JELLYBEAN). Accessing its child works too, fortunately.

Kind regards